# How to get the PID of a recently started process in Bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a bash script file that contains the following code **script.sh**

```
./xxx_program arguments &
PID=$!
echo $PID
kill -INT $PID
```

what I am trying to do is to start a program "`xxx_program`" and then store its `PID` on the `$PID` variable. But instead I keep getting the PID of "`bash`" itself instead of the program I open which causes the `kill -INT $PID` to just quit the `script.sh` while the xxx_program remains running.
Note the `xxx_program` opens but I just get the wrong PID.

I would like to know if there's a way to get the PID of xxx_program? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us your actual script.

Comment: @muru the other parts of the script that I did not show are really irrelevant to solving the problem. The way I wrote it up, is the same way I have it structured on my original script with the exception of "xxx_program" this is because I will not be using this for only one specific program.

Comment: Since `$!` works fine for getting the PID of the last backgrounded command and has worked fine for decades, it is certainly a better option than pidof, pgrep or anything else. If it doesn't work for you, then no, the script is not the same way you wrote it.

Comment: @muru well, whatever you may think. Anyhow it's solved now. Perhaps pidof even though not the quickest, is somehow more reliable?... Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: As you say, "whatever you may think".

Comment: @muru PS: not trying to be rude tho. It just is what it is :p Peace

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are various ways:

1. Let the script write its pid itself. Include line `echo $$ > /tmp/my.pid` in your script.
2. Use `pidof script_name`
3. Use `ps -ef | grep script_name | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f2`

Comment: The last line delivers two results: The pid of the grep is part of it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
pidof xxx_program
```

if that is the name of the process. (must be full process name how it was invoked, including any options or commandline paths)

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked great. "pidof" is definitely a better option compared to what I was doing